# Espresso can not resolve symbol "android.R.id.select_dialog_listview"

Tags: android, android-testing, android-espresso

I am using espresso for my UIAutomation testing.

It is working fine in all cases, but I got an error that I cannot resolve regarding `android.R.id.select_dialog_listview` in this line of code

```
onView(withId(android.R.id.select_dialog_listview)).perform(swipeUp());
```

But in my View Hierarchy tool there exists a Listview with this id.

My espresso dependencies are like below

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
```

Comment: please include xml layout file.

Comment: Do you get a compile error or execution error?

Comment: It is a compilation Error

Answer (score 4):

I had the same, my compiler wasn't finding `R.id.any_id` or `R.string.any_string`. I fixed it by manually importing the correct R, making sure that this line is added:

```
import es.voghdev.progressbuttonview.sample.R;
```

Or more generally

```
import com.yourcompany.yourappname.R;
```

then try to compile again. Hope it works for you too

the exact file where I was having the issue is [this one](https://github.com/voghDev/ProgressButtonView/blob/master/sample/src/androidTest/java/es/voghdev/progressbuttonview/MainActivityTest.java)

Answer (score 0):

Change local resource name to `select_dialog_listview_local`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

The ID `android.R.id.select_dialog_listview` is declared in `select_dialog.xml` that is a layout of the Android SDK, and not every ID of the SDK is exposed outside.

If you are going to test a system dialog (like a SingleChoiceItem), you can be sure that only one ListView is present on top of the screen at that moment. So you can use an assertion like this:

```
onData(anything())
    .inAdapterView(isAssignableFrom(ListView.class))
    .atPosition(0)
    .perform(click());
```